Conditions for a Random Variable to Satisfy a Probability Bound on Boundary Points
Let  $X$ be a random variable supported on $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$, and let $\mathcal{X}$ be compact. Consider $ f $ as the probability density of $ X $.
My question is: What conditions must $ X $ satisfy in order to ensure that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\mathbb{P}(X \in B_{h}(x))=\infty \tag{1}
$$
where $ x $ belongs to the boundary of $\mathcal{X}$ and $ h $ is of the form $ h=\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)^{1/(d+4)} $?
By conditions, I mean those commonly encountered in statistics and probability, such as conditions on the tails or moments, among others that are typical in statistical contexts.
In the 1-dimensional case, I have verified condition (1) for several probability densities, for instance, certain Beta distributions, and found that condition (1) is satisfied. I believe that in the 1-dimensional case, condition (1) will generally be satisfied and that distributions where it is not satisfied will be quite rare.

Take $d=1$, ${\cal X}=[0,1]$, and $f(x)=C x^k$.  Then
$$P(X\in B_h(0))=Ck^{-1}h^{k+1}$$
so for $h=(\log n)/n)^{1/(d+4)}$ we have
$$nP(X\in B_h(0))=nCk^{-1}(\log n)^{\frac{k+1}{d+4}}n^{-\frac{k+1}{d+4}}$$
Note that any positive power of $\log n$ is asymptotically smaller than any positive power of $n$. Now choose $k$ so that $(k+1)/(d+4)>2$ to break the conjecture, eg $k=10$ for $d=1$.
I don't know if you'd consider that a tail bound -- I think of tail and moment bounds as being about behaviour near infinity, but by assumption your $X$ doesn't have any behaviour near infinity.
In higher dimensions I would also worry about the local dimensionality being different from $d$ -- for example, if ${\cal X}$ is the union of a $d$-dimensional ball and a one-dimensional line segment. Just having a density with respect to $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure might be enough to stop that sort of pathology (it stops that example; the question is whether it stops all examples)
